# How to select the last character of a header in a fasta file?

Tags: python, string, sequence, fasta

I have a fasta file like this:

```
>XP1987651-apple1
ACCTTCCAAGTAG
>XP1235689-lemon2
TTGGAGTCCTGAG
>XP1254115-pear1
ATGCCGTAGTCAA
```

I would like to create a file selecting the header that ends with '1', for example:

```
>XP1987651-apple1
ACCTTCCAAGTAG
>XP1254115-pear1
ATGCCGTAGTCAA
```

so far I create this:

```
fasta = open('x.fasta')
output = open('x1.fasta', 'w')
seq = ''

for line in fasta:
    if line[0] == '>' and seq == '':
        header = line
    elif line[0] != '>':
        seq = seq + line


for n in header:
    n = header[-1]
    if '1' in n:
        output.write(header + seq)
    header= line
    seq = ''


if "1" in header:
    output.write(header + seq)

output.close()
```

However, it doesn't produce any output in the new file created. Can you please spot the error?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to read the entire file into a string, and then use `re.findall` with the following regex pattern:

```regex
>[A-Z0-9]+-\w+1\r?\n[ACGT]+
```

Sample script:

```py
fasta = open('x.fasta')
text = fasta.read()
matches = re.findall(r'>[A-Z0-9]+-\w+1\r?\n[ACGT]+', text)
print(matches)
```

For the sample data you gave above, this prints:

```
['>XP1987651-apple1\nACCTTCCAAGTAG', '>XP1254115-pear1\nATGCCGTAGTCAA']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However the body after the header has more than 1000 characters. The script only print a few characters. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Maribet It sounds then like you're not reading the entire file into a string.  Please verify that you have the full text in hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by getting a list of your individual records which are delimited by `'>'` and extract the header and body using a single split by newline `.split('\n', 1)`

```
records = [
    line.split('\n', 1)
    for line in fasta.read().split('>')[1:]
]
```

Then you can simply filter out records that do not end with `1`

```
for header, body in records:
    if header.endswith('1'):
        output.write('>' + header + '\n')
        output.write(body)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I did not get any output. I added 'f = fasta.read()' and modify 'for line in f.split ('>')[1:]', otherwise i got an error AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can quite simply set a flag when you see a matching header line.

```py
with open('x.fasta') as fasta, open('x1.fasta', 'w') as output:
    for line in fasta:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            select = line.endswith('1\n')
        if select:
            output.write(line)
```

This avoids reading the entire file into memory; you are only examining one line at a time.

Maybe notice that `line` will contain the newline at the end of the line. I opted to simply keep it; sometimes, things are easier if you trim it with `line = line.rstrip('\n')` and add it back on output if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly and it is very simple.